# Duda sobre SFINAE

Tags: c++, template, sfinae

¿Como resuelve el compilador el caso en el que puede sustituir mas de un template y no da ambigüedad utilizando el principio de SFINAE.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename U>
U cast(T x){
    return static_cast<U>(x);
    }

template<typename T, typename U>
T cast(U x){
    return static_cast<T>(x);

}
```

si intentamos esto:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    std::cout << cast<int,float>(10) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

se imprime 10, sin embargo si intentamos:

```
 int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    std::cout << cast<int,float>(10.34) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

da el siguiente error de compilacion:

> more than one instance of overloaded function "cast" matches the argument >list: -- function template "U cast(T x)" -- function template "T >cast(U x)" -- argument types are: (double)

¿Alguien sabe por que sucede esto?

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que estás asumiendo que `10.34` es un `float` cuando, realmente, es un `double`. Esto provoca que el compilador se encuentre con dos plantillas candidatas y, debido a que ambas son igual de *malas*, te muestra el error y se queda tan tranquilo.

El error se reproduce igualmente cuando sustituimos las plantillas por funciones *al uso*:

```
float cast(int x){
  return static_cast<float>(x);
}

int cast(float x){
  return static_cast<int>(x);
}

int main(int , char const **)
{
  std::cout << cast(10.5) << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

El error que se genera entonces es el siguiente:

```
prog.cc:18:13: error: call to 'cast' is ambiguous
  int res = cast(10.5);
            ^~~~
prog.cc:5:7: note: candidate function
float cast(int x){
      ^
prog.cc:9:5: note: candidate function
int cast(float x){
```

Ahora bien, volviendo al tema de las plantillas, basta con cambiar la especialización a `double` para que el error desaparezca:

```
std::cout << cast<int,double>(10.34) << "\n";
```

claro que también tenemos, como posible solución, forzar a que el número sea un `float`:

```
std::cout << cast<int,float>(10.34f) << "\n"
```